# Standardize/decompose training/test together or separately?

Tags: machine-learning, standards

Two common ML preprocessing steps on X data are standardization (e.g. scale to unit variance) and decomposition (map the features to a new space, AIUI).

Two possible ways of implementing these steps in a ML pipeline including training/test/validation sets are to :

i) Standardize/decompose on the entire training/test/validation X data set, then break into training/test sets and make predictions on the validation set using the lowest error model.

ii) Break into training/test sets, *then* standardize/decompose training/test sets separately, and make predictions on the validation set using the lowest error model (after standardizing/decomposing it)

Is one of these approaches more preferable than the other, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a third option is valid:

Split into test/training set, compute parameters for standardization/decomposition on training set (e.g. mean and variance of training set for standardization) and apply the same parameters on test set.

For standardization this could mean, that the test set does not have zero mean / unit variance.

Looking at the test set to transform the training set is usually considered bad practice, except for the special case of transductive learning where you have given the inputs of the test set in advance.

Your second option is dangerous since the test set could have outliers that affect the parameters of standardization severly. Hence, it is good to have a single set of transformation parameters that you estimate on the training set.

Comment: found this similar question on CrossValidated that gives the a similar answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i